# How to use Chef DSL inside LWRP's action

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, lwrp

I have LWRP which should create `cookbook_file` inside its `create` action

```
resource_name :vuy
property :vu_name, String, name_property :true
actions :create

action :create do
  log "vuy:@new_resource.vu_name-#{@new_resource.vu_name}"
  cookbook_file "c:/temp/test.xml" do
    source "#{@new_resource.vu_name}"
  end
end
```

And test recipe

```
vuy 'text.txt'
```

`chef-client` execution fails with error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'vu_name' for nil:NilClass`

When I remove `cookbook_file` from `create` method, log correctly shows: `INFO: vu:@new_resource.vu_name-text.txt`
In next step, I replaced

```
    source "#{@new_resource.vu_name}"
```

with same value as specified in test recipe

```
    source "text.txt"
```

and file was fetched.
To me, it looks that `cookbook_file` inner ruby block does not get copy of `new_resource` and it becomes `nil`.

How to use properties of LWRP as arguments of resources declared inside action?

Comment: According to your syntax, you're using the chef 12.5+ custom resource, just remove the `@new_resource` part as per [the doc here](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html)

Comment: That is it.I missed it although I read that document :-)

Answer (score 0):

That should be `new_resource.vu_name`, i.e. without the `@`. With the at sign it's a local variable lookup, without it is a method call. Chef automatically promotes the method call so that even inside the `cookbook_file` you get the right thing, but it cannot do this with an instance variable lookup.